# Field name in URL replaced with "×" on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer

I'm using the jQuery serialize() and window.open function to get the forms data to another page that will print out a file based on the data.

Before the redirect the URL looks OK (console logged the serialized URL):

```
renter_postal_address%5D=&times%5Bstart_date%5D=17.06.2019&times%5Bstart_hours%5D=10&times%5Bstart_minutes%5D=56&times%5Bend_date%5D=17.06.2019&times%5Bend_hours%5D=11&times%5Bend_minutes%5D=56
```

After I reach the desired page the URL looks like this (only on I.E):

```
renter_postal_address%5D=×%5Bstart_date%5D=17.06.2019×%5Bstart_hours%5D=10×%5Bstart_minutes%5D=56×%5Bend_date%5D=17.06.2019×%5Bend_hours%5D=11×%5Bend_minutes%5D=56
```

URL on Google Chrome:

```
?act=rent.fillBookingContractTemplate&item_id=1&data=action=issue_item&item_id=&data%5Bcontract_no%5D=1560762473&data%5Bcurrent_unit_id%5D=&data%5Brenter_personal_code%5D=&data%5Brenter_name%5D=&data%5Brenter_phone%5D=&data%5Brenter_email%5D=&data%5Brenter_postal_address%5D=&times%5Bstart_date%5D=17.06.2019&times%5Bstart_hours%5D=12&times%5Bstart_minutes%5D=07&times%5Bend_date%5D=17.06.2019&times%5Bend_hours%5D=13&times%5Bend_minutes%5D=07&data%5Breturned_to_unit_id%5D=0&data%5Bcountry%5D=Eesti&data%5Breceived_helmets%5D=&data%5Bdocument_id%5D=&data%5Bdocument_issue_date%5D=&data%5Bdocument_valid_to%5D=&data%5Blicence_id%5D=&data%5Blicence_issue_date%5D=&data%5Blicence_valid_to%5D=&data%5Bissuing_comment%5D=
```

URL on Internet Explorer (latest version):

```
?act=rent.fillBookingContractTemplate&item_id=1&data=action=issue_item&item_id=&data%5Bcontract_no%5D=1560762453&data%5Bcurrent_unit_id%5D=&data%5Brenter_personal_code%5D=&data%5Brenter_name%5D=&data%5Brenter_phone%5D=&data%5Brenter_email%5D=&data%5Brenter_postal_address%5D=×%5Bstart_date%5D=17.06.2019×%5Bstart_hours%5D=12×%5Bstart_minutes%5D=07×%5Bend_date%5D=17.06.2019×%5Bend_hours%5D=13×%5Bend_minutes%5D=07&data%5Breturned_to_unit_id%5D=0&data%5Bcountry%5D=Eesti&data%5Breceived_helmets%5D=&data%5Bdocument_id%5D=&data%5Bdocument_issue_date%5D=&data%5Bdocument_valid_to%5D=&data%5Blicence_id%5D=&data%5Blicence_issue_date%5D=&data%5Blicence_valid_to%5D=&data%5Bissuing_comment%5D=
```

Code example that reproduces the error:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET)) {
    var_dump($_GET);
}
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="></script>

<form method="POST" id="item-issuing-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="issue_item">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="275">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[contract_no]" value="1560836285">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[current_unit_id]" value="664">

    <input name="data[renter_personal_code]">
    <input name="data[renter_name]">
    <input name="data[renter_phone]">
    <input name="data[renter_email]">
    <input name="data[renter_postal_address]">
    <input name="times[start_date]">
    <select name="times[start_hours]"></select>
    <select name="times[start_minutes]"></select>
    <input name="times[end_date]">
    <select name="times[end_hours]"></select>
    <select name="times[end_minutes]"></select>
    <select name="data[returned_to_unit_id]"></select>
    <select name="data[country]"></select>
    <input name="data[received_helmets]">
    <input name="data[document_id]">
    <input name="data[document_issue_date]">
    <input name="data[document_valid_to]">
    <input name="data[licence_id]">
    <input name="data[licence_issue_date]">
    <input name="data[licence_valid_to]">
    <textarea name="data[issuing_comment]"></textarea>

    <button type="button" class="go-test">Go</button>
</form>

<script>
    $('.go-test').on('click', function () {
        window.open('index.php?item_id=275&data=' + $('#item-issuing-form').serialize(), '_blank');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is sometimes the side-effect of using polyfill libraries that are not well written. Just check if what you're using for a date picker in IE can work properly with `serialize`

Comment: But the serialized URL looks OK in my opinion.. the "Before the redirect the URL looks OK" part in my initial question. Also the output is the same on google chrome.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my side using IE 11.116.18362.0 version and the [jquery .serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method, the url doesn't contains the 'x'. 

Besides, from the URL, it seems that only part of the parameters contains the 'x', you could check try to use F12 developer tools to check these elements and check the value. And, you could try to use F12 developer Network tools to check the request.

Comment: I've edited the inital question with code that can reproduce the problem for me.

Comment: you're using POST as form method but passing data using GET, as well as dumping GET data. try typical input type=submit and try to dump data using POST

Comment: Method POST works but.... In my original code I have a button type "button" that first sends the form data using the serialize() function and then submits the form using submit() function. The idea behind this is to first get the file from the serialized data straight to the users browser in a different tab and simutaniously submit the form to actually save the data to database.

Comment: jQuery's `.serialize()` method produces an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded string which you appear to be attempting to assign to the `data` parameter within the URL's own `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` query string. This isn't going to work. It would look like `&data=action=issue_item&...` You either need to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the serialized form and assign it to `data` or remove `data=` and just append the serialized form

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help, I finally solved the problem but putting the data to an object and then using this function to make it URL friendly:
var URL_data = decodeURIComponent($.param(data));

I also put the times object into the data object which seemed to be the main problem